# How to get Sql Instance names of remote server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to get all SQL instance names (default & named) when supplying a computer/server name. The main issue I have is that on an environment that uses both availability groups and FCI, I can not manage to get the full name for the FCI named instances. Obviously, with an AG you can simply use computername\namedInstance, but with a FCI named instance you require the full name. I need a reliable way of achieving this that is also fast.

This [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/six-methods-to-automatically-discover-sql-server-instances/) is the main one I have been using, but I have read through 10+ other articles and none seem to provide the result set I require.

Edit:

```
$machines = 'myClusterName'
foreach ($machine in $machines) {get-clusterresource -Cluster $machine -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| where-object {$_.ResourceType -like “SQL Server”} | get-clusterparameter VirtualServerName,InstanceName | group-object ClusterObject | select-object @{Name = “SQLInstance”;Expression = {[string]::join(“\”,($_.Group | select-object -expandproperty Value))}}}
```

The above code is able to accurately grab the exact names of my SQL Server named instances that utilize Failover Cluster Instance for high availability, but I still need to grab named instances that utilize availability groups.

Our current cluster contains server that have a default instance of SQL (Availability group on the default 1433 port), named instances (Failover Cluster Instance) and Named instances (Availability group on a static unique port that is referenced by servername/namedinstancename)

Comment: What have you tried? If you can provide your sample code, along with more details about how it is not meeting your expectations, that will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Code has been added that grabs named instances, but I am still having trouble generating a list that contains all of the proper names for each of my SQL instances on a given server.